# mean of an image opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, mean

I'm not certain about my mean function. In Matlab, the mean of my image is  `135.3565` by using `mean2`; however, my function gives `140.014` and OpenCV built-in `cv::mean` gives me `[137.67, 152.467, 115.933, 0]`. This is my code.

```
double _mean(const cv::Mat &image)
{
    double N = image.rows * image.cols;
    double mean;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < image.rows; ++rows)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < image.cols; ++cols)
        {
            mean += (float)image.at<uchar>(rows, cols);
        }
    }
    mean /= N;

    return mean;
}
```

Comment: What do you suppose the value of `mean` is before the loop starts?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, the sum of all pixels' values divided by its total number.

Comment: **Before** the loop starts.

Comment: an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Right ;)  So does that answer the question?

Comment: Nope. I did initialized it and I got same answer. My question is why it varies? Does it have something to do with aligned bytes?

Comment: I think your image is an RGB image since your mean is in an array of three(mean of B G R channels)!

Comment: @Constantine, you are right. The image is RGB. In this case, should I include the bytes for each pixels as independent elements? In my code it doesn't seem like that.

Comment: This is how Matlab computes the mean `y = sum(x(:), [], 'double') / numel(x);`

Comment: @CroCo, In opencv just compute the mean of that three values, it'll give you the same thing as matlab will!

Comment: @Constantine, each pixel has three values(BGR). What do you mean by `the mean of that three values`

Comment: @CroCo, I meant the mean of the three mean values you computed from opencv built-in function (`[137.67, 152.467, 115.933]`).If you do this you will get what matlab will give you!

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that you are feeding one type of image to Matlab and another type to your algoritm and to the opencv built-in function.

The mean2 function of Matlab takes a 2D image (grayscale) . Your function assumes that the image is 2D matrix of unsigned chars (grayscale too), and when you do this:

```
mean += (float)image.at<uchar>(rows, cols);
```

and you pass a color image to the function, an incorrect value is retrieved. Try to convert your image to grayscale before passing to your function and compare the result with Matlab.

For a color image, modify your function to this:

```
double _mean(const cv::Mat &image)
{
    double N = image.rows * image.cols * image.channels();
    double mean;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < image.rows; ++rows)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < image.cols; ++cols)
        {
            for(int channels = 0; channels < image.channels(); ++channels)
            {
                mean += image.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows, cols)[channels];
            }
        }
    }
    mean /= N;

    return mean;
}
```

and in Matlab compute the mean with

```
mean(image(:))
```

which will vectorize your image before compute the mean. Compare the results.

The opencv function computes the mean of each channel of the image separately, so the result is a vector of the means of each channel.

I hope this will help!